# JS function works from console, but onclick returns blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on some HTML5 app with JS, and I've encountered a problem. Function written in js is working when called from console, but when clicking on button with onclick it returns a blank page.

here's the function:

```
function open() {
document.getElementById("chatBox").innerHTML = localStorage.chat;
return false;
}
```

and here's button:

```
<button id="openConButton" onclick="open()">Open</button>
```

Oh, and important one: other function from this script file are working just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your button inside of a form?

Comment: `<button type="button">...</button>` with the type attribute

Comment: It isn't inside a form, but others aren't inside form eighter, and they still works, with other functions of course

Comment: Common pitfall; your button is calling "document.open()". Just rename the function.

Comment: Thanks! you can answer, and I'll mark it :)

Comment: @MikeC This is more for curiousity sake, but would that matter if the click is tied to a JavaScript function and not a form submit?

Comment: you also shouldn't use the onclick html attribute and global scope functions. You should attach the click event handler with javascript and keep your code, variables, and functions in another scope (ie. functions and IIFEs)

Comment: @War10ck [Yup. It totally matters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms) ;)

Comment: @MikeC Ah, ok, I misunderstood where you were going with that. Thanks for thel link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common pitfall; your button is calling `document.open()`. Just rename the function.